# Bootstrap Modal Backdrop not Covering buttons and Fields

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

I'm using mysql and php, I've created just a single page user.php for user, in which the center `<div>` content is updated through php everytime any link on the same page is click. Incase I'm not clear, when user click on a link in side bar in user.php, a specific variable is sent with the page link, like `user.php?form` and then if `form` is not empty, the center `<div>` brings form to display. This works fine, but for some links, I didn't used this method, I used modal instead. When a specific variable is not empty, php calls to a function `modal()`, declared in another `methods.php` file and modal brings the required content based on the parameters passed through function call, everything up till here works great except the backdrop of modal, first it was over modal content, but after I set its `z-index:-1` it went to back but some content behind the modal is not under backdrop, like buttons, header, input fields are of the same brightness as is modal. I searched for it, and found the "Append the modal to body" solution, but my modal is not on my page, it is being called from a separate file through php. I just want the backdrop to cover all elements like it should. Screenshot of modal is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnKD8.jpg).

My user.php file, which calls modal based on a specific variable

```
<div class="col-sm-10" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
<?php
$result2 = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username'")
or die("failed to query database".mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    if(isset($_GET['pwd']) && !isset($_GET['done']))
    {
      $userId=$row2['Id'];
      $value=4;
      $s=4;
      modal($value,$userId,$s);
    }
    if(isset($_GET['noti']))
    {
      $_SESSION['visited']=true;
      notific($username);
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['home']))
    {
      home();
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['about']))
    {
      about();
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['contact']))
    {
      contact();
    }
    else
      submitForm(0);
    ?>
</div>
```

And methods.php file, which contains modal declaration, user.php file only calls modal for `pwd` but I used same `modal()` function from panels other than users', which explains the constant value checking in modal body.

```
function modal($value,$idnum,$s)
    {
        echo  '<script>
                    $(function() {
                     $("#myModal").modal("show");
                    });
                </script>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"    >
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">';
                        if($s==1 || $s==2)
                          echo 'Closing Details';
                        else if($s==4)
                          echo 'Edit Account';
                        else if($s==3)
                          echo 'Confirm?';
                        else if($s==5)
                          echo 'Add New Case';
                        echo '</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="fetched-data clearfix">';
                          if($s==6)
                            addCr();
                          else if($s==5)
                            submitForm(1);
                          else if($s==4)
                            pwdChange($idnum,$value);
                                else if($s==2)                              
                                        display($idnum);
                                    else if($s==1)
                                        form($idnum);
                                echo'</div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
        if($value==1)
            allRecords();
    else if($value==2 || $s==6)
      criminals();
        else if($s!=4 && $s!=5)
            oneRecord($value);
    else if($s==5)
      allRecords();
    }
```

I can't seem to find what is causing this, I even tried to set the input fields' z-index to a negative number, but nothing changes.
P.S. I know I'm not "supposed" to use mysql, so spare me with that advice for now, any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The HTML and the underlying CSS output would had helped to understand the problem better.
However, I have created a codepen for your reference. https://codepen.io/mburnette/pen/bVWaOO

A modal is defined to be

```
.modal{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

Unless a non-static positioned element with a z-index > 1050 is placed on there should be no issue. I also see that the modal dialog is not centre aligned. I assume, that the CSS of .modal has been overridden somewhere in CSS.

Comment: I didn't create a single css stylesheet, every class used is called from bootstrap, and the modal is center aligned, the screenshot I provided doesn't show side panel.

Comment: Can you provide for the generated HTML for the page? along with the css that you are using in a codeine or something? or a direct link? I should be able to help you with it.